Acceso de una funcion al label de una clase en otro archivo
Estoy con un proyecto hecho para mi propio aprendizaje en python y pyqt5. En resumen, ahora mismo es una app con una ventana inicial que tiene 2 botones y 2 label, uno para un cartel en la parte superior y otro para la imagen de fondo. Despues de esto hay otra vista, usando QStackedWidget, la cual tiene 2 text input (usuario y contraseña) y un botón de login.
Como vereis en el repositorio, ahora mismo hay 3 archivos, funciones.py (donde guardo todas las funciones usadas) main.py (donde esta la clase principal y la configuracion de la primera ventana)
y por ultimo una carpeta con los recursos (imagenes, musica y css) usados en la app.
Necesito que al pulsar el botón login, además de lo que ya hace, que es iniciar musica y abrir un mensaje, cambie la imagen del label ubicado en la clase main, que esta en el archivo main.py. La funcion para esto está en el archivo funciones.py, en comprobarlogin. El problema es que no se como hacer que la funcion pueda acceder a los atributos del label para cambiar la imagen, siempre me salta el error de que el atributo no existe o parecidos.
Gracias de antemano. Si necesitan alguna informacion mas no hay problema, aun asi, dejo el repositorio publico para que podais verlo todo.
Repositorio github
